# extract from each element of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
ll = ['listA_5_val','listB_15_val','listC_25_val']
```

and I would like to create a new list based on this:

```
new_list = [5,15,25]
```

where we have extracted the number from each list. I can do this for a single element like this:

```
ll[0][6:-4]
```

How do I do this to entire list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> ll = ['listA_5_val','listB_15_val','listC_25_val']

>>> [int(x[6:-4]) for x in ll]
[5, 15, 25]

>>> [int(x.split('_')[1]) for x in ll]
[5, 15, 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, with a list comprehension it can be done this way:

```
arr = [int(i[6:-4]) for i in ll]
```

And will result in: `[5, 15, 25]`

Answer (score 1):

For each element, one of the better ways would be to use `str.split` to cut the element into three parts, and then convert the middle part to an integer:

```
int(element.split("_")[1])
```

To do this for every element, the most pythonic way would be to use list comprehensions:

```
new_list = [int(element.split("_")[1]) for element in ll]
```

Answer (score 1):

if there is only one time digit in string:

```
import re
ll = ['listA_5_val','listB_15_val','listC_25_val']
[ re.findall('\d+',x)[0] for x in ll ]
```